# android.support.v8 cannot be resolved

Tags: android, renderscript

I am trying to use `renderscript` in my Android project. I installed `sdk tools 22.6.2` and `sdk build tool 19.0.3` and then updated my adt to the latest version. But now I get error that 
"The import android.support.v8 cannot be resolved" on the line where I wrote import `android.support.v8.renderscript.*`. I have also made the following changes in `projects.properties`

```
renderscript.target=18
renderscript.support.mode=true 

sdk.buildtools=19.0.3
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.amazing.imazing"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.amazing.imazing.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I am new to Android programming.

Comment: Please post your AndroidMenifest.xml

Answer (score 3):

I removed all the entries from the project.properties except the one 'target=android-18' and copied the renderscript-v8.jar to the libs folder of my project. I found this jar file in sdk/build-tools/18.1.0/renderscript/lib. I stopped getting that error.

I repeated this process in another project and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
renderscript.target=18
renderscript.support.mode=true
sdk.buildtools=18.1.0
```

Comment: I tried this but still same problem. i also tried to add existing code to workspace but v8 is not available on my system v4 v7 and v13 are there but on selecting v13 nothing is listed in the project box.

Answer (score 0):

Which **IDE** are you using? Pay attention to the fact that Android Studio/Gradle-based builds are [not yet supported](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html#access-rs-apis) by the RenderScript support library.

In addition, IntelliJ IDEA ignores the `project.properties` file, even if you are using the default build system ("make").